# deferred/promise js mecanism on multiple firebase storage upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, jquery-deferred, firebase-storage

i'm stuck with image upload to firebase database asynchronous mecanism in my project, here's my problematic:

***i have a form where user put some info, the user also need to provide 4 photo to complete the upload process.***

i use firebase database & firebase storage to handle this, here's the flow :

- user fill form1 form2 & form3 with text based info
- user select img1 img2 img3 img4 image from his computer
- user clic submit all 4 image upload to firebase and give me 4 download url
- i append all previously gathered information + 4 download url in a dictionary and ship it to firebase database

so the my deal is to create and ship the dictionary only when and if the 4 photo url are set, i heard about deferred/promise concept but i see a lot of Ajax request and no one with a similar issue, here is what i have for now

```
$("#submit-bag").click(function () {

    var uploadDfdimg1 = function() {
        var deferred = new $.Deferred();
        var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + $img1.name).put($img1);
        uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
        }, function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
        }, function() {
        var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
        console.log(downloadURL);
        url1 = downloadURL;
        deferred.resolve(downloadURL);

        return deferred.promise();
        });
    }
    var uploadDfdimg2 = function() {
        var deferred = new $.Deferred();
        var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + $img2.name).put($img2);
        uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
        }, function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
        }, function() {
        var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
        console.log(downloadURL);
        url2 = downloadURL;
        deferred.resolve(downloadURL);

        return deferred.promise();
        });
    }
    $.when(uploadDfdimg1,uploadDfdimg2).then(
        function(){console.log('double trouble success')},
        function(){console.log(url1 + " deferred")},
        function(){console.log(url2 + " deferred")});


    var brand = $("#select1 option:selected").text()
    var mail = document.getElementById('form1').value
    var postal_code = document.getElementById('form2').value
    var comment = document.getElementById('comment').value
    //UPLOAD IMG

    //uploadImg(img1,url1);
    //uploadImg(img2,url2);
    uploadImg(img3,url3);
    uploadImg(img4,url4);

    //console.log(url1);
    //console.log(url2);
    console.log(url3);
    console.log(url4);
    //PHOTO LINK VAR
    var postData = {
        marque: brand,
        email: mail,
        code_postal: postal_code,
        commentaire: comment,
        //PHOTO LINK
        validation: 0
    };
    var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('submission').push().key;
    var updates = {};
    updates['/submission/' + newPostKey] = postData;
    firebase.database().ref().update(updates)
```

like you can see here, img3 & img4 upload themselves using the old non fonctionnal manner (downloadUrl come after the all dictionary PostData is send)

for img1 & img2 i tryed to use Deferred to see if i can get the 2 url at the same time when $.when.().then fired, normally after the success promise of the two uploadDfdimg function

the result is, i instantly get the "double trouble" log message with empty url variable, and normally after a second, the two url returned by firebase for img3 and img4

[return log of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/454ul.jpg)

how can i be able to asynchronously send 4 image to firebase, get the url, and at the end of this process, put the url in my dictionary to send it to my database ?

Comment: Your uploadDfdimg functions do not return a promise. In fact they return undefined as they have no return value

Comment: .then with 3 arguments? Where did you pluck that code from?

Comment: The code starting at var brand will execute before the .then code above it

Comment: Your code is no different from all the ajax code on SO. You just haven't grasped how promises work

Comment: that's a fact, but i don't know where to start from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question appears to ask for the following type of approach.

First a utility function, which promisifies the upload process and delivers a promise-wrapped `downloadURL`.

```
function uploadImg(img) {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
        var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + img.name).put(img);
        uploadTask.on(
            'state_changed', 
            function(snapshot) {}, 
            function(error) { dfrd.reject(error); }, 
            function() { dfrd.resolve(uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL); }
        );
    }).promise();
}
```

Now, that utility can be used to create 4 x promises, which can then be aggregated with `$.when()` :

```
$("#submit-bag").click(function () {
    var p1 = uploadImg(img1);
    var p2 = uploadImg(img2);
    var p3 = uploadImg(img3);
    var p4 = uploadImg(img4);
    $.when(p1, p2, p3, p4).then(function(downloadUrl1, downloadUrl2, downloadUrl3, downloadUrl4) {
        // Whatever you want to do with downloadUrl1, downloadUrl3, downloadUrl3, downloadUrl4, ...
        // ... do it somewhere in this function.
        var updates = {};
        updates['/submission/' + firebase.database().ref().child('submission').push().key] = {
            marque: $("#select1 option:selected").text(),
            email: $('#form1').val(),
            code_postal: $('#form2').val(),
            commentaire: $('#comment').val(),
            validation: 0
        };
        firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
    });
}
```

More concisely, you would probably write :

```
$("#submit-bag").click(function () {
    var promises = [img1, img2, img3, img4].map(uploadImg);
    $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function(downloadUrl1, downloadUrl3, downloadUrl3, downloadUrl4) {
        // Whatever you want to do with downloadUrl1, downloadUrl3, downloadUrl3, downloadUrl4, ...
        // ... do it somewhere in this function.
        // etc, as above
    });
}
```

Comment: what i was trying to achieve was that firebase database function are async, but to create and submit my form, i need those url, so the need was to wait the confirmation that my 4 photo are online, to take generated url and fill my form before submit it too

Comment: Mehdi, the overall temporal logic of my answer should be correct for your purpose, but I'm not too sure about the detail. If `#submit-bag` is the form's submit button, then you need to inhibit submission (with `event.prevcentDefault()`). You probably also need to write the download URLs to form fields before forcing the form programatically to submit.

Comment: yes, with your help it's solved now, not the cleanest way (i still use multiple function and break the don't repeat yourself principle, more clear like that for me)  but still functionnal